# Use constant from other class Symfony

Tags: php

How to use a constant in a `class A` in other `class B`

```
class Filter {
     private const OR_OPERATOR = 'or'
    // ...
}

class Query {

    public function buildQuery(Filter $data): AbstractQuery
    {
        if ($data->getOperator() === 'or') {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use the `OR_OPERATOR` class constant in the class `Query` ?

Comment: You can't access a private constant from outside the class. You need to define it as public. More info about class constants: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the name of the class and the `::` operator.

E.g.:

```
 if($data->getOperator() === Filter::OR_OPERATOR)
```

Of course, this won't work in your example because you declared the constant `private`. If you declare it `private` you mean it's not to be used from outside this class' instances or static methods.

If you need to use it from elsewhere, just change the visibility to `public`.